# SVG element not getting selected - Bar chart not being displayed

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I am trying to create a simple bar chart using the following code. There seems to be some issue with svg element due to which the bar chart is not getting displayed in the browser window. The only output I get is "Bar Chart using D3.js". I am using MacOS+Chrome.

Also I am not sure if `"<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/3.0.10/polyfills.js"></script>"` is required

Following files are index.js and index.html respectively.

```js
var dataset = [80, 100, 56, 120, 180, 30, 40, 120, 160];

var svgWidth = 500,
  svgHeight = 300,
  barPadding = 5; //ht and wt
var barWidth = (svg / dataset.length); //each bar wt

var svg = d3.select('svg') //give attr of wt and ht
  .attr("width", svgWidth)
  .attr("height", svgHeight);

var barChart = svg.selectAll("rect") //create bar chart with rect
  .data(dataset) //provide dataset
  .enter() //takes data from waiting state perform operation
  .append("rect")
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return svgHeight - d
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr("width", barWidth - barPadding)
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      var translate = [barWidth * i, 0]; //[x axis, y axis]
      return "translate(" + translate + ")"; //translate one bar after another
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <title>Basics of D3.js</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Bar chart using D3.js</h1>
  <svg class="bar-chart"></svg>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/3.0.10/polyfills.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you try and run the snippet? There's a syntax error in your JS.

Comment: Accounting for the syntax error, what is your bar width: `var barWidth = (svg / dataset.length);`, do you mean `var barWidth = (svgWidth / dataset.length);` as `svg` is not defined yet, though even when it is defined, it's a selection of an svg, not a number.

Comment: @AndrewReid Got it.. its svgWidth. Sorry for the goofup! Thanks a ton! :)